# JS - add string after each word

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a text:

```
<div id="xxxx">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </div>
```

I would like to create a function that takes minimum 2 arguments.

```
const inputDiv = document.getElementById("xxxx");
const string1 = "copying forbidden"
addTextBetweenWords(inputDiv, string1)
```

Let's say that string ones is "copying forbidden".

If somebody copies the full text, or part of the text contained in the div `inputDiv`, the result will be the same text. For example, the final text copied will be:

```
Lorem copying forbidden ipsum copying forbidden dolor copying forbidden sit copying forbidden amet copying forbidden, consectetur copying forbidden adipiscing copying forbidden elit copying forbidden, sed copying forbidden do copying forbidden eiusmod copying forbidden tempor copying forbidden incididunt copying forbidden ut copying forbidden labore copying forbidden et copying forbidden dolore copying forbidden magna copying forbidden aliqua.
```

Can anyone suggest how to make such function in vanilla js, that will work with ctrl-c as well as using the mouse right click.

I am not asking a ready solution, it can be help to understand how to write it. But if somebody wants to put the solution and explain it, I will be glad too. I just want to understand it. I am wondering if I have to split it, edit it, and re join it, or there are simple methods.

Comment: something like `div.textContent=div.textContent.split(/\s+/).join(" Copying Forbidden ")`

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be hard to prevent people from copying text from the browser, but you can use the `.replace` function to do that:

```js
const inputDiv = document.getElementById("xxxx");
const string1 = "copying forbidden"
addTextBetweenWords(inputDiv, string1)

function addTextBetweenWords(words, text){
  words.innerHTML = words.innerHTML.replaceAll(" ", `${ text }`)
}
```

Comment: Elements don't have a replace method . And when replace()ing a string with a string, only the first instance is replaced... Your edit also removes spaces, resulting in a jumble of letters. Why template the string if it's used un-modified?

Comment: nice catch, I edited the answer to use replaceAll and innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) it globally:

```js
function addTextBetweenWords(element, text){
  content = element.innerHTML
  regex = new RegExp(' ', 'g');
  content = content.replace(regex, " "+text+" ")
  element.innerHTML = content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
const inputElement = document.getElementById("xxxx");
const copyrightString = "do not copy";

const replaceWhitespacesWithString = function (){
    const newText = inputElement.innerText
    .split(/\s+/) // splits by whitespaces
    .join(" "+copyrightString+" "); // re-assembles it with the content of 'copyrightString' as a glue.
    
  document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML = newText;
}
```

Live-Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/ezs1r8op/7/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copiedEvent() {
  let text = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  const words = text.split(' ');
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = words.map(word =>  word + " copyright prohibited ").join('');
    
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" oncopy="copiedEvent()">Try to copy this text</div>
 <div id="res"></div>
```